# How do I avoid an infinite loop when overriding a virtual property?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to ignore set and get when I'm assigning to or retrieving a value?

In specific, I'm inheriting from a class that has a property declared like this:

```
virtual public Int32 Value { get; set; }
```

What I'd like to do is to override it and do something useful in those set and get's. The problem appears when I override it, I also have to manually assign, or return the value from the property. If I do something like this:

```
override public Int32 Value
{
    get
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Value = value;
        // do something useful
    }
```

Then I'm creating an infinite loop. Is there a way to set or get the value without invoking the code in set and get, or do I have to make a separate name for the actual variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `this.Value`, you should be using `base.Value`.  That will retrieve/set the property in the base class.

Note that the base method actually has to be overridable (`virtual` or `abstract`); in your example it's not.  If the base method is not virtual then you'll just get a compiler error when you try to override in the derived class.

Comment: Well, it actually is virtual, I just forgot to type it in here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you are after is `base`, [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx).  This forces the compiler to resolve the property reference to the one defined in the base class.  The VB.NET Equivalent is MyBase.

Thus:

```
get 
{ 
    return base.Value; 
} 
set 
{ 
    base.Value = value; 
    // do something useful 
}
```